# React native expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Подскажите как мне добавить все вариации иконок для андройд, будь то xxxhdpi или hdpi, что б он сам выбирал нужный. На данный момент в коде так:

```
"android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
```